# How to update and move object with pathfinding?

Tags: java, game-engine, path-finding, slick2d, 2d-games

I've implemented some pathfinding in my 2d game, but I don't know how to move my  'Zombie' character.
I'm using slick2d and everything gets put on the screen in the render method, however I want to update the zombies movement in the Zombie class.
Here is the method in the zombie class:

```
  public void findPrey(){

    Pathfinder pf = new Pathfinder();
    pf.setStartNode(xPosition,yPosition);

    for(PathCoordinates p: pf.calculatePath()){

        if(p.getXPosition() > xPosition){
            moveRight(2);               
        }if(p.getXPosition() < xPosition){
            moveLeft(2);
        }if(p.getYPosition() > yPosition){
            moveUp(2);
        }if(p.getYPosition() < yPosition){
            moveDown(2);
        }
    }
}
```

So I want to loop through the List of x and y coordinates and move the zombie.
However nothings happens- the zombie doesnt move at all.

In my 'world' class I have the render method, which loops through the zombies and renders them, the code has been edited slightly:

```
    public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g)
        throws SlickException {


        for (Zombie z : zombies) {

        if (!z.isDead()) {

            z.render(gc, sbg, g);
            z.findPrey();


        }

    }

}
```

So, basically my question is how - do I make my zombie character move?! Thanks for any help or guidance

Comment: Yeah I have something similar in the moveUp() and other similar methods

Comment: It looks like you render the output and then move the Zombie...

Answer (score 0):

You should first move the zombie, then render it.
There's another problem: you allow to move the zombie all the way it should with one `findPrey()` (using `updatePosition()` in code below) method call.

Zombie class:

```
public void updatePosition() {
  Pathfinder pf = new Pathfinder();
  pf.setStartNode(xPosition,yPosition);
  PathCoordinates p = pf.calculatePath()[0];
  if(p.getXPosition() > xPosition) {
    moveRight(2);               
  } if(p.getXPosition() < xPosition) {
    moveLeft(2);
  } if(p.getYPosition() > yPosition) {
    moveUp(2);
  } if(p.getYPosition() < yPosition) {
    moveDown(2);
  }
}
```

World class:

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
  for(Zombie z : zombies) {
    if(!(z.isDead())) {
      z.updatePosition();
      z.render(gc, sbg, g);
    }
  }
}
```